# How do I fix this "T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING" error?

Tags: php, debugging, syntax

I am writing a simple php registration page using MySQL as the database. I am quite new to it and I came across this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting
>   T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\w4wregister.php on
>   line 34

I have gone through the little bit of code that I added that caused that error for the past hour and cannot see anything wrong with it. Below I have the code I added. I believe I was able to narrow it down to the `while` statement but I gave the other code for context.

```
if($r) {

echo "<h1>Thanks for registering!<h1><br/><h2>Current Users:</h2>";

$q2 = "SELECT username AS users FROM users ORDER BY registration_date";

$r2 = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q2); //gets all users

if ($r2) {

echo '<table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" width="25%"><tr><td>Username</td></tr>';


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

echo "<tr><td> $row['users'] </td></tr>";

}

echo "</table>";

} else {

echo "Hey, that didn't work!";
}
```

Comment: Where are the "}" for the "if" statemens?

Comment: @Pekka im not exactly sure, seems like different numbering than what I am using for editing it.

Comment: @Mironor yeah, thanks I just realized that one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
echo "<tr><td> $row['users'] </td></tr>";
```

To:

```
echo "<tr><td> {$row['users']} </td></tr>";
```

Another option would be:

```
echo "<tr><td> ".$row['users']." </td></tr>";
```

Or even:

```
echo "<tr><td> ", $row['users'], " </td></tr>";
```

See the [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) for more examples of how to employ variable interpolation.

Comment: Haha, _exactly_ the same! :-)

Comment: @JoostK nah, you're missing the colons and capitalization of the "to" :P

Comment: @BoltClock: it certainly is. It causes a `T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE` error as the OP listed. The error your answer refers to would be `unexpected $end`.

Comment: @Stephen: I would take a look at `D` as well. If you're echoing a string with *many* concatenations, converting it to echo arguments will be several times faster. But in the OP's case, I also think `C` is most appropriate (most readable).

Comment: "several times faster" is conjecture, and I'm leaning towards it being incorrect.  The difference in speed for PHP 5.3 is usually >1 millisecond.  Micro-optimizations like this aren't worth the trouble.  As a matter of fact, the version of PHP you use can change which one is more efficient.

Comment: It's precompilation vs interpreted concatenation. Check it out for yourself. Others have run the numbers. As far as version affecting the difference, I'll take your word for it. But using a comma instead of a period isn't really much trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
echo "<tr><td> $row['users'] </td></tr>";
```

to

```
echo "<tr><td> {$row['users']} </td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($r) 
{

    echo "<h1>Thanks for registering!<h1><br/><h2>Current Users:</h2>";

    $q2 = "SELECT username AS users FROM users ORDER BY registration_date";

    $r2 = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q2); //gets all users

    if ($r2) 
    {

        echo '<table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" width="25%"><tr><td>Username</td></tr>';


        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

            echo "<tr><td>" . $row['users'] .  "</td></tr>";

        }


        echo "</table>";
    } //this was not there

} 
else 
{

    echo "Hey, that didn't work!";
}
```

Comment: Or he missed the closing bracket for the first if-statement, you can't tell.

Comment: hehe, I took a chance;) But thought it seemed more logical that way. (As much as possible here)

Comment: sorry, I missed the closing bracket for the first if-statement

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo "<tr><td> ".$row['users']." </td></tr>";
```

Instead of

```
echo "<tr><td> $row['users'] </td></tr>";
```